# Webpack 2 & 3 Promise for IE10/11

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm looking at upgrading from Webpack 1 all the way through to Webpack 3 however, I am aware that I need to load in a [promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) polyfill. Now I have managed to do this but ideally I'd really like to only load the Polyfill code if I'm on a browser that needs it.

Now obviously I can't simply load it through the normal require.ensure etc. way via Webpack as this is the thing that needs Promise.

The only thing I can think is to have a simple if statement near enough at the start of my JS bootup to check and basically having a script.onload type function that is the bootup in that scenario. Any ideas or ways that this already can be done that I haven't managed to find would be great cheers.